# Можно ли с онлайн видео плееров как то вытянуть поток?

Tags: видео

Можно ли с онлайн видео плееров как то вытянуть поток? То есть припустим есть какое-то видео онлайн, можно ли как-то заполучить поток и выводить это в самописном плеере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае можно.

Comment: не могли бы подсказать в какую сторону рыть? Наверное Flash, если иметь дело с Flash плеерами?

Comment: Иногда можно вытянуть саму ссылку, она бывает "запрятана" в коде. Т.е., после некоторых усилий её удаётся отловить. Либо мониторить HTTP-заголовки при старте плеера. Готовые плагины бывают.

Answer (score 1):

в firefox есть такой add-on называется DownloadHelper